# Debian Kickstart Files Failing To Download

Tags: kvm, kickstart, preseed

I have found that if I try to host my kickstart files on github and pass the raw url to `virt-install`, such as below, it will fail.

```
http://raw.githubusercontent.com/programster/KVM-Command-Generator/master/kickstart_files/debian_wheezy.cfg
```

```
┌────────────┤ [!!] Download debconf preconfiguration file ├────────────┐
│                                                                       │
│             Failed to retrieve the preconfiguration file              │
│ The file needed for preconfiguration could not be retrieved from      │
│ http://raw.githubusercontent.com/programster/KVM-Command-Generator/ma │
│ ster/kickstart_files/debian_jessie.cfg. The installation will proceed │
│ in non-automated mode.                                                │
│                                                                       │
│                              <Continue>                               │
│                                                                       │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

However, if I take the same content, and dump it into pastebin like below, it will work:

```
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JEZn5Q5n
```

#### Question

Is there a maximum length on kickstart file addresses that will work or is there something else going on such as character encoding in the response or line endings etc?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is with https protocol as github redirects all requests to https. Seems like Ubuntu initrd (tested trusty) does not support or it's kickstart realization lacks https.
When kickstart file is downloaded via http, it works just fine.